# P-adic expansions of Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

> Is there a way to prove that  $a$ is an element of the Integers, if $p$ is prime, $a$ is in $\mathbb Z_p$ and its $p$-adic expansion is eventually periodic?

I know how to do this for the rationals, but it's not clear to me how to prove this for the integers...

Comment: But... isn't an integer a fortiori rational ? In any case for an integer the p-adic extension is not only periodic, it's actually finite (meaning it's eventually zero).

Comment: Finite in case the integer is nonnegative; for negative integers, the coeffs of $p^n$ will eventually all be $p-1$.